# Is the question about CAPM vs PMP certifications too localized?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

I answered [Can I apply for PMP without experiences in all processes? What are the requirements for obtaining these certifications?](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/6603/applying-pmp-without-experiences-in-projects-with-budget) after doing some research on the PMI website. It wasn't until I was halfway done with my answer that I began to suspect that this question might be too localized:

> **too localized**
>   This question is unlikely to help any future visitors; it is only relevant to a small geographic area, a specific moment in time, or an extraordinarily narrow situation that is not generally applicable to the worldwide audience of the internet. For help making this question more broadly applicable, see the FAQ.

This really depends on the context, and not having a CAPM or PMP myself, I'm not sure how often this material changes. If the requirements for these certifications change too often, then this question may need to be closed. If this material doesn't change very often, then I'm not too worried.

How often do these requirements change? Is this limited to a specific moment in time, where the answer I posted won't be valid in 6 months to a year?

Comment: I think this question (my question) is borderline. Of course the single part *budget* can be too localized. However the most relevant sentence in your answer is *You should have experience in all five process groups* which isn't too localized (in my opinion).

Comment: Okay @MarcoDaniel, I was sort of thinking the same thing, except maybe the other way around. The budget part of the question added some specifics and actually prevented the question from being not a real question or not constructive. I had to dig in a bit to find the answer, which is good, IMHO. I overdid it a bit in my answer, so perhaps we may edit this down to just the parts that are unlikely to change and also make a point to add a note referring people to the PMI website for "official" updates. Thanks for weighing in and for contributing to PMSE! Welcome to our community! :)

Comment: What do you think about the following title: *Can I apply for PMP without experiences in all processes?* -- In detail I can explain my issue in the question itself. I am happy finding this site ;-)

Comment: That's a great suggestion, it would maybe help other people find the question easier, since someone else may have a question about a different process group. However, I personally like that the body of your post is more specific. Those types of questions tend to do better here than ones that are too broad. So title yes, but as for the body I'd suggest waiting for more community input, lest we take things too far in the opposite direction. :)

Comment: Can we pre-emptively shut down all questions that ask for interpretations of PMI rules? There is a simple way to get answers about PMI questions and it doesn't involve asking people other than PMI.  I do not want PM:SE to answer "X is true" only to have PMI inform the user "X is not true."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regardless of being too localized or not, PMP / CAPM questions and any other PM-certification related question (I believe) are the kind of questions that might attract audience to pmse.

Having them well organized and properly answered just like you did, for sure will add value to the community. So, I would not consider this question too localized *to the point of close it down*.

I'd suggest, as a rule of thumb, to just edit them and keep them as much useful as possible.

Comment: I was thinking of making the answer community wiki so it's more widely editable. What do you think?

Comment: 100% agree! It's done :)

Comment: Hey @TiagoCardoso, sorry for the confusion. I was referring to [my answer here](http://pm.stackexchange.com/a/6607/34). :) lol.

Comment: Haha, no worries, @jmort253 :)